# How to print title from SPAN tag

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

How can I print out the title from inside this span tag?

When I use

```
puts row.css('td.calendar__impact').css('span').title
```

it returns empty:

```
irb(main):063:0> rows.map do |row|
irb(main):064:1*  puts row.css('td.calendar__impact').css('span')
irb(main):065:1> end
```

Using the HTML:

```
<span title="Low Impact Expected" class="low"></span>
<span title="Low Impact Expected" class="low"></span>
```

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". Your sample HTML doesn't match the code so it'll fail to demonstrate the problem. Don't make us generate the HTML to match your code as it wastes our time and can induce errors or wrong answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
row.css('td.calendar__impact').css('span')
```

is returning an array, so you might want to loop though it to get the title for all the span elements.

This is how you would access the attributes and get the title for the first span element:

```
row.css('td.calendar__impact').css('span')[0].attributes['title'].text
```